# I keep getting a "Form submission canceled because the form is not connected" whenever I submit any of the forms inside my react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, antd

I've antDesign forms in my component and i keep getting this error on the console `Form submission canceled because the form is not connected` .

Those are 2 of the forms I have under VerifyComponent, which is nested under the main component.

```js
{tasky.map(item => {
                                const VerifyComponents = () => {
                                    if (item.type === "rate") {                                      
                                        return (
                                            <>
                                                
                                                            <Form className="login-form" onFinish={(formData) => onsendrate(formData)} key={`rate${item.id}`}>
                                                                <Form.Item
                                                                    name="useryrate"
                                                                    rules={[
                                                                        {
                                                                            required: true,
                                                                            message: '',
                                                                        },
                                                                    ]}
                                                                    initialValue={userIdD}
                                                                    hidden
                                                                >
                                                                    <Input size="large" prefix={<UserOutlined className="site-form-item-icon" />} placeholder="" />
                                                                </Form.Item>
                                                                <Form.Item
                                                                    name="toskyrate"
                                                                    rules={[
                                                                        {
                                                                            required: true,
                                                                            message: '',
                                                                        },
                                                                    ]}
                                                                    initialValue={item.id}
                                                                    hidden
                                                                >
                                                                    <Input size="large" prefix={<UserOutlined className="site-form-item-icon" />} placeholder="" />
                                                                </Form.Item>
                                                                <Form.Item>
                                                                    <Button key="submitButtonrate" className="login-form-button" htmlType="submit" type="primary" shape="round" size="large" icon={<MailOutlined />} loading={loadings[item.id]} onClick={() => enterLoading(item.id)} style={{ boxShadow: '0 5px 20px rgba(94, 74, 227, .6)', width: '100%' }}>
                                                                        done
                                                                    </Button>
                                                                </Form.Item>
                                                            </Form>
                                                    <Form onFinish={oncrackst} key={item.id}>
                                                        <Form.Item
                                                            name="taskyy"
                                                            rules={[
                                                                {
                                                                    required: true,
                                                                    message: '',
                                                                },
                                                            ]}
                                                            hidden
                                                            initialValue={item.id}
                                                        >
                                                            <Input size="large" prefix={<UserOutlined className="site-form-item-icon" />} placeholder="username" />
                                                        </Form.Item>                                                       
                                                        <Form.Item
                                                            name="screen"
                                                            rules={[
                                                                {
                                                                    required: true,
                                                                    message: '',
                                                                },
                                                            ]}
                                                            hidden
                                                            initialValue={fileUrl}
                                                        >
                                                            <Input size="large" prefix={<UserOutlined className="site-form-item-icon" />} placeholder="" />
                                                        </Form.Item>
                                                        <Form.Item className="justify-end">
                                                            <Button htmlType="submit" type="primary" shape="round" size="large" icon={<CheckOutlined />} loading={loadings[item.id]} onClick={() => enterLoading(item.id)} style={{ boxShadow: '0 5px 20px rgba(94, 74, 227, .6)', width: '100%' }}>
                                                                done
                                                            </Button>
                                                        </Form.Item>
                                                    </Form>
                                                </div>
                                            </>
                                        );
                                    }
```

I've tried creating a component at the top level to store the Form and it didn't work, giving Id's to each form didn't work either. could it be the mapping? but it's kinda necessary in my case here.